# Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

$L^2(-1,1)$

$f_1(x)=1+x$ , $f_2(x)=2-x $ , $f_3(x)=1$

I know the algorithm and what it does, but it's not clear how to proceed.
I think it would be better to take as "weight function" $f_3(x) $ .
$\hat{f}_1(x)=f_1(x) $
$\hat{f}_2(x)=f_2(x)-<\hat{f}_1,f_2>\hat{f}_1(x) $
I think.

Comment: If you don't know how to proceed, then you don't know the algorithm or what it does.

Comment: I always used it for vectors, and as first impact, with function I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand - if you know the algorithm, why don't you know how to proceed?

Note that
$$
\left|f_1(x)\right|^2
 = \left<f_1, f_1 \right>
 = \int_{-1}^1 f_1^2(x)dx
 = \int_{-1}^1 (1+x)^2dx
 = 8/3.
$$
Indeed,
$$
\hat{f}_1(x) = \frac{f_1(x)}{|f_1(x)|} 
             = \frac{f_1(x)}{\sqrt{8/3}}
             = f_1(x)\sqrt{3/8}
$$
and you define $\hat{f}_2(x)$ correctly. Can you compute it, and define and compute $\hat{f}_3(x)$ similarly?